# Как в pandas правильно применить оператор and (&)?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть множество дата фреймов (в примере их несколько), мне нужно проверить каждый из них на наличие ключевых слов в первом столбце. Для получения нужного дата сета я должен получить два (или более совпадений), в обычной ситуации это решается через оператор 'and', но применить его в pandas не получается (я знаю что в pandas оператор 'and' обозначается как '&').
В тоже время оператор 'or' ('|') прекрасно работает. Но проблема в том что '|' для выполнения условия достаточно хотя бы одного совпадения, а мне нужно несколько.
Я понимаю что с оператором '&' будет проверятся оба условия, которые будут применяться к каждой строке в дата фрейме, я хотел бы узнать можно ли применить условия к целому столбцу и не построчно ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re


df_16 = pd.DataFrame({"number": ["onE:    ", "  Two:", np.nan, "fIve", "four@", "tHree", "   one", "tWo", "tWo     SIx", "one"], 'phone': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 300, 77, 1000, 1, 5],
 "item": ["debt", "phone", "room", "go", "hoot", "aaple", "orange", "phone", "tool", 'hoooo'],
  "seria": [1050.34344343, 150, 544, 245, 230, 50, 300, 70, 33, 100]},
  index=['q', 'e', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y', 'j', 'v', 'm', 'g'])

df_17 = pd.DataFrame({"number": ["onE#", "tWo:", "six      ", " fiVE   ", "four", "thRee:", np.nan, "twO", "two Six", "Two fOr"], 'phone': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 300, 77, 1000, 1, 5],
 "item": ["debt", "phone", "room", "go", "hoot", "aaple", "orange", "phone", "tool", 'hoooo'],
  "seria": [1050.34344343, 160, 544, 245, 230, 50, 300, 70, 33, 100]},
  index=['q', 'e', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y', 'j', 'v', 'm', 'g'])

df_18 = pd.DataFrame({"number": ["gggg", "TTt", "HHHH     ", " HJkl   ", "green", "redd", np.nan, "twO", "nuul", "Null"], 'phone': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 300, 77, 1000, 1, 5],
 "item": ["debt", "phone", "room", "go", "hoot", "aaple", "orange", "phone", "tool", 'hoooo'],
  "seria": [1050.34344343, 160, 544, 245, 230, 50, 300, 70, 33, 100]},
  index=['q', 'e', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y', 'j', 'v', 'm', 'g'])

list_data = [df_16, df_17]

for i in list_data:
    i['number'] = i['number'].fillna('empty') # заполняет nan значения 
    i['number'] = i['number'].agg([lambda do: re.sub(r'[#@:]', ' ', do)], axis=0) # убирает ненужные символы
    i['number'] = i['number'].agg([lambda do: re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', do)], axis=0) # убирает двойные (или больше) пробелы
    
    # переводит строк в нижний регистр, убирает пробелы (которые остались), поиск совпадений
    check = (i['number'].astype(str).str.lower().str.strip().str.fullmatch('two (six|for)') & i['number'].astype(str).str.lower().str.strip().str.fullmatch('six')) 
    if check.any():
        getting = i
        print(getting)        
        print(check)
```

Я отчасти решил эту задачу, выполнял проверку по ключевым словам, по отдельности, но это будет неправильно когда понадобится искать много ключевых слов.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re


df_16 = pd.DataFrame({"number": ["onE:    ", "  Two:", np.nan, "fIve", "four@", "tHree", "   one", "tWo", "tWo     SIx", "one"], 'phone': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 300, 77, 1000, 1, 5],
 "item": ["debt", "phone", "room", "go", "hoot", "aaple", "orange", "phone", "tool", 'hoooo'],
  "seria": [1050.34344343, 150, 544, 245, 230, 50, 300, 70, 33, 100]},
  index=['q', 'e', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y', 'j', 'v', 'm', 'g'])

df_17 = pd.DataFrame({"number": ["onE#", "tWo:", "six      ", " fiVE   ", "four", "thRee:", np.nan, "twO", "two Six", "Two fOr"], 'phone': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 300, 77, 1000, 1, 5],
 "item": ["debt", "phone", "room", "go", "hoot", "aaple", "orange", "phone", "tool", 'hoooo'],
  "seria": [1050.34344343, 160, 544, 245, 230, 50, 300, 70, 33, 100]},
  index=['q', 'e', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y', 'j', 'v', 'm', 'g'])

df_18 = pd.DataFrame({"number": ["gggg", "TTt", "HHHH     ", " HJkl   ", "green", "redd", np.nan, "twO", "nuul", "Null"], 'phone': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 300, 77, 1000, 1, 5],
 "item": ["debt", "phone", "room", "go", "hoot", "aaple", "orange", "phone", "tool", 'hoooo'],
  "seria": [1050.34344343, 160, 544, 245, 230, 50, 300, 70, 33, 100]},
  index=['q', 'e', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y', 'j', 'v', 'm', 'g'])

list_data = [df_16, df_17]

for i in list_data:
    i['number'] = i['number'].fillna('empty') # заполняет nan значения 
    i['number'] = i['number'].agg([lambda do: re.sub(r'[#@:]', ' ', do)], axis=0) # убирает ненужные символы
    i['number'] = i['number'].agg([lambda do: re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', do)], axis=0) # убирает двойные (или больше) пробелы
    
    check = i['number'].astype(str).str.lower().str.strip().str.fullmatch('two (six|for)') # Проверка 1
    check_1 = i['number'].astype(str).str.lower().str.strip().str.fullmatch('six') # Проверка 2
    
    if check.any() and check_1.any():
        print(check)
        print(check_1)
        getting = i
        print(getting)
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить из `list_data`. Пока не очень понятно что и как вы хотите сделать...

Comment: list_data это список с дата сетами, из которого нужно получить дата сеты отвечающие условию

Comment: советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Я так и не понял как должен выглядеть результат

Comment: number   phone    item        seria
q     onE         11       debt         1050.343443
e     tWo        22       phone       160.000000
r     six           33        room       544.000000
t    fiVE          44          go         245.000000
u     four         55        hoot       230.000000
y     thRee      300      aaple       50.000000
j      empty     77      orange      300.000000
v     twO        1000   phone       70.000000
m    two Six      1       tool         33.000000
g    Two fOr      5      hoooo     100.000000

Comment: получения конкретного дата сета

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом, чтобы привести пример результата прямо в вопросе. В комментариях невозможно отформатировать данные